# How do I say "Who is the tallest in your family?"

Tags: grammar, translation

Is this correct? 
家族に中で背が高い誰ですか。

Comment: to add to the answers below, you could also say 家族(の中)で一番背が高い**のは**誰ですか。

Answer (score 3):

You would use の instead of に here (linking two nouns), so 家族の中.

You also want to insert a superlative (phrase that means "most"/"best"/#1).  One example is 一番（目）. There are many others, like もっとも, だれより（も） (less common), etc.

So something like:

> 家族の中で一番背が高い人は誰ですか。

For some basic examples of superlatives, see [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Comparisons#Superlative).

Comment: We do not say 「だれもより」 to mean anything.

Comment: Ah, yikes, that's a bad typo.  だれより or だれよりも, depending on the situation.  I'll fix it, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1. Generally speaking **に** is used to mark a place in space or time, you'll want to use **の**　in **家族の中で**.
2. i-adjectives(形容詞) are followed immediately by a noun, therefore **高い誰ですか** which is followed by a "question word" is not grammatically correct.

If you want to be polite use this:

> 御家族で最も背の高い方はどなたでしょうか？

if not, the answer above is best.